# Does this prove $X \times Y$ is countable if $X$ and $Y$ are countably infinite sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I want to show that if $X$ and $Y$ are 2 countably infinite sets, then $X \times Y$ is countable. My argument is that we could number the elements of $X$ by giving an arbitrary element thereof $0$, then another element $00$, another element $000$, etc.; and number $Y$ in the same manner but instead using $1$'s not zeroes. Then, every element $(x,y)$ of $X \times Y$ is a unique binary string if we put together $x$ and $y$; so the Cartesian product has cardinality at most that of the set of binary strings, and the set of binary strings is countable. Therefore $X \times Y$ is countable.

I am unsure of my argument because I do not know whether it is possible to number every element of an infinite set, as this process cannot be completed. I have tried to justify this by likening it to the nature of Cantor's diagonalization, which also takes an infinite amount of time. If this does work, what would be the reason why a process taking an infinite amount of time like numbering the elements of an infinite set works?

Comment: Yes, this is fine. By definition a set is countably infinite iff it can be placed in bijection with the natural numbers, so countable sets are already "numbered." In mathematics we don't think of this process as taking place in time at all (or, if you prefer, we imagine that we can reason about the output of infinite processes even without being able to "actually" perform them).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is it accurate to say we have as an axiom that infinite processes can be completed, so we say that *if* infinite processes can be completed, all of these things whereof we speak are possible? I am trying to reconcile what you said at the end about how we can regard infinite processes having an output although they can't be performed in our world

Comment: Sort of? It's complicated. Let's get more concrete: essentially any interesting mathematical statement makes infinitely many claims at once. Already if I say something like "addition of natural numbers is commutative" I am saying that if you take any positive integer $m$ and any positive integer $n$ then $m + n$ is the same as $n + m$. But why do I believe I know that? After all, to actually check this statement for every pair of positive integers $m, n$ is countably many cases.

Comment: The reason I believe I am able to know infinitely many things in this way even though I can't check each of them individually is because I believe the principle of mathematical induction. In the same way, induction can be used to define, for example, sequences like the Fibonacci numbers, even though to believe that the Fibonacci numbers are well-defined for *all* $n$ requires that we apply the Fibonacci recursion infinitely many times. This is stuff you have to get used to if you want to do almost any interesting mathematics at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your confusion arises from conflating the act of defining an injection $f:X×Y->N$, with the process of actually *evaluating* $f((x,y))$ at every point of the infinite set.

Your argument is correct; given injections $g:X->N, h:Y->N$, we can define $f$ by constructing a string of $h(x)$ ones followed by $g(y)$ zeroes, treat it as the binary expression of an integer $n=f((x,y))$, and then all that remains is to prove that no two pairs $(x,y)$ generate the same $n$.